# Type error:View must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include() in django 2.0

Tags: python, django

*i have python 3.6 and django 2.0 installed. i keep having this same error...Type error:View must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include() in django 2.0*

**`my app urls`** the app's name is catalog

```
from django.urls import path
from django import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('index/',
         views.catalog_home, name='catalog_home'),
    path('category/<category_slug>/',
         views.show_category, name='show_category'),
    path('product/<product_slug>/',
         views.show_product, name='show_product')
]
```

**my project urls** this is the projects urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls'),),
    path('static/', static,
         {
             'document_root': 'C:/Users/USER1/PycharmProjects/untitled13/static'
         }),
]
```

**my views**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from catalog.models import Category, Product
from django.template import RequestContext


def index(request, template_name='catalog/index.html'):
    page_title = 'online shop for all items'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def show_category(request, category_slug, template_name='catalog/category.html'):
    c = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = c.product_set.all()
    page_title = c.name
    meta_keywords = c.meta_keywords
    meta_description = c.meta_description
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name='catalog/product.html'):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
    categories = p.categories.filter(is_active=True)
    page_title = p.name
    meta_keywords = p.meta_keywords
    meta_description = p.meta_description
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Post your whole error message with full traceback please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the actual reference of static. Change `static` to `static.serve` in `urlpatterns`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls'), ),
    path('static/', static.serve,
         {
             'document_root': 'C:/Users/USER1/PycharmProjects/untitled13/static'
         }),
]
```

Reference : [Serving files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve)

Comment: Yeah, an oversight. Thanks.